# Populating gridview based on database info when logged in session based

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview, database-connection

I'm having trouble with populating a gridview based off of logging in with a session based login. I'm using a master page. Currently I am getting a "must declare scalar variable". My thought is to retrieve it somewhere in the script area. Any help is greatly appreciated!!!!

The problem now is what the code should be for the non-master page to retrieve the specific information for someone based of their uname(column in database) or UID(primary key and ideal way)
Code for master page (relevant stuff at least)

```
    protected void btnlogin2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (btnlogin2.Text == "Login")
    {

        string strCmd = "Select * From Person Where uname=@uname and upass=@upass";
        SqlConnection objConn = new SqlConnection(strConn);
        SqlCommand objCmd = new SqlCommand(strCmd, objConn);
        objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname", txtusername.Text);
        objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@upass", txtpassword.Text);


        using (objConn)
        {
            objConn.Open();
            SqlDataReader objDR = objCmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (objDR.Read())
            {

                Session["uname"] = txtusername.Text;

                if (objDR["Type"].ToString() == "Member")
                { Response.Redirect("member.aspx"); }
                else if (objDR["Type"].ToString() == "Pledge")
                { Response.Redirect("member.aspx"); }
                else if (objDR["Type"].ToString() == "Admin")
                { Response.Redirect("eboard.aspx"); }



            }
            else
            {


               // btnlogin2.Text = "Failed";

            }
        }
        btnlogin2.Text = "Logout";
    }
    else if (btnlogin2.Text == "Logout")
    {
        btnlogin2.Text = "Login";
        txtusername.Visible = true;
        txtpassword.Visible = true;
        pnlSideBar.Visible = false;

        Session.Abandon();
        Response.Redirect("index.aspx");

    }
    btnlogin2.Text = "Failed";
}
```

Code for page

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Debug="true" MasterPageFile="masterpage.master"  %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.SqlClient" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Configuration" %>

<script runat="server">

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strConn = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cloud2"].ConnectionString;
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            Button btnlogin2 = (Button)Master.FindControl("btnlogin2");
            TextBox txtusername = (TextBox)Master.FindControl("txtusername");
            TextBox txtpassword = (TextBox)Master.FindControl("txtpassword");
            Panel pnlSideBar = (Panel)Master.FindControl("pnlSideBar");
            Panel pnlPledge = (Panel)Master.FindControl("pnlPledge");
            Panel pnlEboard = (Panel)Master.FindControl("pnlEboard");


            string strCmd = "Select * From Person Where uname=@uname";
            SqlConnection objConn = new SqlConnection(strConn);
            SqlCommand objCmd = new SqlCommand(strCmd, objConn);
            objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname", Session["uname"]);




            using (objConn)
            {
                objConn.Open();
                SqlDataReader objDR = objCmd.ExecuteReader();

                if (objDR.Read())
                {
                    btnlogin2.Visible = true;
                    btnlogin2.Text = "Logout";
                    txtusername.Visible = false;
                    txtpassword.Visible = false;
                    if (objDR["Type"].ToString() == "Admin")
                    {
                        pnlEboard.Visible = true;
                        pnlPledge.Visible = false;
                        pnlSideBar.Visible = false;

                    }
                    else if (objDR["Type"].ToString() == "Member")
                    {
                        pnlEboard.Visible = false;
                        pnlPledge.Visible = false;
                        pnlSideBar.Visible = true;

                    }
                    else if (objDR["Type"].ToString() == "Pledge")
                    {
                        pnlPledge.Visible = true;
                        pnlEboard.Visible = false;
                        pnlSideBar.Visible = false;
                    }
                    lblLogin.Text = "Logged in as:  " + objDR["Fname"] + " " + objDR["Lname"];
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>


   </asp:Content>
   <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphText" runat="server">
  <div id="mainContent">
    <h1> My Service Hours</h1>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <table width="318" height="126" border="1" cellspacing="1">
      <caption>
        Event   Event Date   Hours
      </caption>
      <tr>
        <th width="100" scope="col">Polar Plunge</th>
        <th width="100" scope="col">1/13/12</th>
        <th width="100" scope="col">5 hrs</th>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <form id="form3" name="form2" method="post" action="">
      <label for="Totalhrs"></label>
      Total: 5hrs
    </form>
      <asp:GridView ID="grvServiceHours" DataSourceID="srcServiceHours" runat="server"/>
      <asp:SqlDataSource
        id="srcServiceHours"
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:cloud2 %>"
        SelectCommand="select Event.Event_Name, Event.Event_Time, Event.Event_Type, Service_Hours.Hours, Service_Hours.Hours_Completed
                       from Event, Service_Hours, Person
                       where Event.EvID=Service_Hours.EvID and Person.UID=Service_Hours.UID and Person.Uname=@uname"
        Runat="server" />
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <!-- end #mainContent --></div>
    </asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a propery in your master and use it any where on your content page rather than a variable. Master page property is accesible any where on the content page by adding a directive in your aspx page.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions as to how to go about doing this? Any would be great. Thanks

Comment: Following link contains full informatio that is required in your app.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx